# jQueryUI datepicker for date-range is failing to validate when date text box is cleared with keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, daterangepicker

I am using jqueryUI datepicker for a date range as in this [demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range). This is failing to validate To as future date to From in the following case:

1. In FROM date choose 11/19/2011. Now go to Nov month of the 2011 in the TO datepicker, you can't pick the date before "11/19/2011". This is fine and expected behaviour
2. Now place your cursor in FROM date picker textbox using the mouse. Select the picked date i.e 11/19/2011 and delete i.e make the textbox empty.  At this point of time 2 textboxes are empty.
3. Now go to 'TO' datepicker Check for NOV 2011. All the dates before 11/19/2011 are still disabled which is not required behaviour.

To solve this I made textboxes `readonly` but i want a better solution for this issue so that user can enter the date with keyboard as well as pick  with mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the logic for setting `minDate` and `maxDate` is located in the `select` event listener (which does not get fired off when you completely remove a date from a datepicker field). You could bind to the `change` event instead:

```
var dates = $("#from, #to").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 3,
}).bind("change", function() {
    var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
        selectedDate = this.value,
        instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
        date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat ||
             $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
        dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);        
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/TMnRX/

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrew It works. I have added 'change' event in addition to onSelect event. Keep sharing your knowledge.

Comment: @KyasaMadhavi: Thanks for the kind words. Glad to help!